# How to prevent sass from inluding styles from loaded modules?

Tags: sass

I'm using a workflow where after generating the main styles normally, I use the [JS API](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/) to generate secondary styles from other entry points with some additional post-processing.

There are [modules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/#:%7E:text=use%20are%20called-,%22modules%22,-.%20Sass%20also%20provides) that are common between the main and secondary processes, but I want the style rules from these common files to be included only on the main styles (otherwise I have duplicates).

How do I prevent sass from including loaded styles into the CSS output?

Or tap into the functionality I know it's there somewhere because the [`@use` docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/) say:

> styles loaded this way will be included **exactly once** in the compiled CSS output

So at least if sass believes the modules have already been loaded once, it will prevent the styles from being included in the output (grabbing only variables, functions and mixins).

Thank you.

PS:

- Using intermediary files with `@forward` would still include styles in output.
- I do not wish to modify files with a configuration pattern to condition adding styles, nor to split files into variables and style rules only files. I want the build system to take care of it automatically.